# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property even after importing RouterModule

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular-ui-router, router

I have a simple component

```
<p>selector works!</p>
<a [routerLink]="['../']">
    <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
</a>
```

that should include a back button. However I get the error

```
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'
```

even though the `RouterModule` is imported in the module in which the `selector.component` is declared

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SelectorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

The problem can be solved by importing `MyModule` in `app.module`.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the module with call to `forRoot` or `forChild` method of the `RouterModule`.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SelectorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]), // with array of routes 
  ]
})
```

Comment: why importing RouterModule is not enough?

Comment: I don't know good documentation giving a clear answer. Looking into https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#description I can reason that this ensures the providing of Router only once per app

Comment: why importing RouterModule is not enough?  -> Because Angular must know if the route is root one or child one.

Comment: And if there is no need to set routes for a module?

Answer (score 1):

If your selector component is part of any other module.

You should import `RouterModule` there also in imports array.

Or else

Check whether you have imported `selector` component properly

Comment: why importing MyModule in the AppModule is needed?

Comment: If you are about to use more than router-outlet. with different modules.

It's require to import it.

In appmodule- you will use `forRoot` | for sub module you have to use `forChild`

Comment: I got that but why? It looks like that some modules and realted directive are not included for the components declared in other modules unless the declaring modules are imported in AppModule

Comment: Ya you are right, It's depended on package publisher. 
If you want create new module where you can import all the required packages and import that module into app.module once with `forRoot`. so it will available to all modules